# Assign a constant value in a trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, triggers, quotes

I am learning triggers in PostgreSQL.

I have created a trigger function `update_name()`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_name()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    NEW.name := "ankit";
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION update_name()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

My table `user_table` is:

```
CREATE TABLE user_table (
  name character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  password character varying(20),
  email character varying(20),
  gender character varying(20),
  phone bigint,
  CONSTRAINT user_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

and the trigger for the table is :

```
CREATE TRIGGER "change-name"
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON user_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_name();
```

when I am inserting data to my table using query:

```
INSERT INTO user_table(name, password, email, gender, phone)
VALUES ('aa', '9874', 'poi@ka.in', 'male', 8978987896);
```

I've got the error:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "ankit" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT "ankit"
>                ^
> QUERY:  SELECT "ankit"
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function update_name() line 3 at assignment
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: column "ankit" does not exist
> SQL state: 42703
> Context: PL/pgSQL function update_name() line 3 at assignment
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about PostgreSQL syntax. I removed irrelevant references to pgAdmin from the question.

In Postgres, literal values (constants) are enclosed in single quotes: `'value'`.
Double quotes are reserved for identifiers but optional as long as it consists of legal, lower-case letters: `"Odd Name"` vs. `odd_name`.

This is also the SQL standard. Start by reading the chapter ["Lexical Structure" in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

Answer (score 0):

The ERROR has gone by changing just:

```
NEW.name := "ankit";
```

to

```
NEW.name := 'ankit';
```

Why is it so???

Comment: Why is it so? - Because that's how SQL works. Identifiers are quoted using double quotes, string constants are written using single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_name()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
     RAISE NOTICE 'RECORD IS INSERTED %',NEW.name;
            INSERT INTO user_table VALUES("ankit",NEW.password,NEW.email,NEW.gender,NEW.phone);
            RETURN NEW;
        end if;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION update_name()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Try this out this will help you.